# DB Error when running python manage.py loaddata datadump.json

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, mysql-error-1062

I'm migrating my Django database from sqlite to mysql. I've done the following with no problems:

python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
Change your settings.py to the mysql database.

But when I issue the following command **python manage.py loaddata datadump.json** I get this error:

**IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '13-13' for key 'from_category_id'")**

Can someone tell me how to go about fixing this issue so that I can run the command again and hopefully load my data?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: 1. Do you have existing data in the DB?

Comment: yes, I have data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have existing data in theDB?,
2. try with indent --4 to get a version that you can eyeball
3. Post some sample data
4. It looks like you got a duplicate key violation or your data you are trying to insert does not match the column type i.e check the constraints applied in your models.py, field types, and the tables created in mysql

The question then will be why does it work in SQLITE and not my sql?

Simple really, SQLITE does not do any type checking, i.e you could easily insert text into an integer field. You will need to clean your data before inserting it into MySQL.

> Unlike most SQL databases, SQLite does
>   not restrict the type of data that may
>   be inserted into a column based on the
>   columns declared type. Instead, SQLite
>   uses dynamic typing.

From http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Thanks for reply back. Silly question, do I check the mysql database or the sqlite database? I don't which one I should edit at this point. :D

Comment: Actually you want to check your 1. Your models vs your data vs mysql db. I.e if there is inconsistent data in the exported JSON (text in a field that should be an integer). In any case, not sure why you have this prob as even thou SQLITE does not do type checking, i am pretty sure the django admin stops you from inserting incorrect values. So have you done some updates outside of the admin?

Comment: I could never figure out the problem. So, because the project is small, I simply created another project, migrated my data over to the new project, then: python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json, Changed my settings.py, syncdb'ed, then python manage.py loaddata datadump.json Looks like it worked. When I have some more time on my hands I'll have to go back and see what went wrong. Thanks.